# Export Eclipse Compiler to cmd

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, mingw

I try to compile an eclipse-project written in c++ which is building a .so-File. Now i try to build the project without an IDE. I tried it with MinGW but the created .so doesn't work. I think there are used some special packages but how can I get the information's.

Is there a way to Export the build settings and import them into MinGW?
How can i else set the compiler?

This is the [ToolChainEditor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFS8M.png) which i would recreat in MinGW.

Answer (score 0):

You can't import a configuration into mingw, but you can tell mingw where to find a configuration of sorts.

Eclipse can be configured to [generate a makefile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile) (At least as recent as Neon). Select your project and use the main menu to navigate Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Tool Chain Editor. Set the "Current builder" to Gnu Make Builder and build the project.

In the generated folder where you would find the finished executable you will find three more files: makefile, objects.mk and sources.mk and can use the `make` utility that often comes with mingw. It can also be downloaded separately if you have to.

From the command line, enter the folder and type `make`. Magic will happen. If you want to know more about the magic, `make` is a very deep topic well worth learning, even if only as a gateway drug to more modern build systems that descended from it.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. I am new into all of that. Can I post a picture of the Tool Chain Editor here?